# Ubuntu server crashes. print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector

Tags: 18.04, server

All the websites on the server lost connection to Database, and this is now happening every day in the morning. Only way out from this is to restart server using restart button on the PC, because server is totally crashed.

Ubuntu server version **Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS**

Error log:

```
    [85660.334392] systemd-journald[508]: Failed to rotate /var/log/journal/80dbc055                                      82ee4d1ea0fd6ba43ae7f381/system.journal: Read-only file system
[85660.334409] systemd-journald[508]: Failed to rotate /var/log/journal/80dbc055                                      82ee4d1ea0fd6ba43ae7f381/user-1000.journal: Read-only file system
[85660.334893] systemd-journald[508]: Failed to write entry (21 items, 690 bytes                                      ), ignoring: Input/output error
[85660.335048] systemd-journald[508]: Failed to rotate /var/log/journal/80dbc055                                      82ee4d1ea0fd6ba43ae7f381/system.journal: Read-only file system
[85663.995342] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#18 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET d                                      riverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[85663.995349] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#18 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 0d 7f 6b a0 00 00 80                                       00
[85663.995352] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 226454432
[85663.995389] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#19 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET d                                      riverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[85663.995392] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#19 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 0d 7f 6b a0 00 00 08                                       00
[85663.995395] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 226454432
```

I don't know what information should I else provide, but if something else is needed I can provide it.

Smartool report:

```
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x02) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7d) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        No Auto Offline data collection support.
                                        Abort Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (  48) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x0025) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x0032   120   120   050    Old_age   Always       -       0/0
  5 Retired_Block_Count     0x0033   100   100   003    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours_and_Msec 0x0032   083   083   000    Old_age   Always       -       154
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       633
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  0x0030   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       39
177 Wear_Range_Delta        0x0000   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1
181 Program_Fail_Count      0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
189 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0000   026   035   000    Old_age   Offline      -       26
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   026   035   000    Old_age   Always       -       26
195 ECC_Uncorr_Error_Count  0x001c   120   120   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0/0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0033   100   100   003    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
201 Unc_Soft_Read_Err_Rate  0x001c   120   120   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0/0
204 Soft_ECC_Correct_Rate   0x001c   120   120   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0/0
230 Life_Curve_Status       0x0013   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       100
231 SSD_Life_Left           0x0000   096   096   011    Old_age   Offline      -       1
233 SandForce_Internal      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       138
234 SandForce_Internal      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       665
241 Lifetime_Writes_GiB     0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       665
242 Lifetime_Reads_GiB      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       926
244 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   097   097   010    Old_age   Offline      -       747

SMART Error Log not supported

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     15480         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     15088         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Seems like everything is ok.

Comment: Because of the "I/O error, dev sda, sector 226454432" message, I'd first check the health of your drives (esp. whichever drive/array is sda) using SMART (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools) then I'd likely just `fsck` (*file system check*)...

Comment: I used smart to check drives statuss and all seems ok. So I cant figure out where is the problem.